# Calculating optimal window size

Tags: tcp, networking

I'm currently trying to calculate the optimal window size. I got these variables:

- Propagation delay: 10 ms
- Bit speed: 100 kbps
- Frame size: 20 bytes

When the propagation delay is 10 ms we get a limit when the window size is 13 and when the propagation delay is 20 ms we get a limit when we have a window size of 24.

Is there any formula to calculate the maximum window size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula to your Question is:

(Bitspeed*2*tp)/buffer*8 = windowsize

Where:
Bitspeed = 100 in your case
2*tp = RTT (The time it takes to send and return a package), which in your case is 20
And buffer = 20, 20*8 to get the bitsize
Windowsize = the thing you want calculated

Hope I was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth times delay. It's called the bandwidth-delay product.